# Cordova or ionic chat bot implementation

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, chat, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

we developed the cordova mobile application using angular js, we are trying to add the chat bot (chat service) feature in our application any one have implemented same feature in the cordova or hybrid mobile application please let me know the best way to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [api.ai](https://api.ai/) or [wit.ai](https://wit.ai/docs) they both have a lot of libraries so you can integrate it with your platform of choice , in your case you can use http .
You can also have a look on [this github repo](https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-cordova-sample) it contains a sample that uses api.ai to create a chatbot in an apache cordova app

Comment: Hi  @Fady   thanks for your ans but its not my ans ,api.ia is not provide the ready to use SDK in cordva mobile app, i required to use ready to integrate in the exting cordova mobile app,can you suggest which service provider   is best

Comment: No sir Api.ai provides an sdk for cordova check this link from the official documentation https://api.ai/docs/sdks

Answer (score 0):

Before starting implementing below code, first read and clear your basics about intent, entities, fulfilments, and create one agent.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basics

As your project in cordova so below is quick start implementation -

Install api.ai plugin with Cordova CLI:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apiai
```

Add to your **index.js** file (typically in **js** folder) in function **onDeviceReady** following code

```
ApiAIPlugin.init(
        {
            clientAccessToken: "YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN", // insert your client access key here
            lang: "en" // set lang tag from list of supported languages
        }, 
        function(result) { /* success processing */ },
        function(error) { /* error processing */ }
    );
```

The ApiAIPromises init method will connect the application to the "Dialogflow project", it needs a client access token which is available there inside settings of the agent.

If you want make text requests add the following code:

```
function sendText(query_text) {
    try {
        ApiAIPlugin.requestText(
            {
                query: query_text
            },
            function (response) {
                // place your result processing here
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            function (error) {
                // place your error processing here
                alert(error);
            });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check this [nodejs-dialogflow](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow) library.

Here is a [GitHub example](https://github.com/Kommunicate-io/Kommunicate-Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Chat-Plugin) you can use to get you started and check this [link](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/building-ionic-cordova-chatbot-dialogflow-api-ai/) for more details